# Resuming debug from the middle in pycharm

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

This should be a common issue and I believe it should have been asked somewhere! But I couldn't find a wording that leads my search to an answer!

Suppose you have a python program that runs for 1 hour! The issue that you want to debug and ultimately rerun (possibly in several rounds) happens after 45 mins! Is there a way to kinda Cache or save your variables in debugger space, and rerun the program from that point onwards? (Especially for Python/Pycharm). I already thought of Pickling my variables but first, there are too many variables and second, not all objects can be pickled in python!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Proper way**:
You can accomplish this with the [post-mortem functionality from pdb](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html). [[more info]](https://paris-swc.github.io/python-testing-debugging-profiling/07-debugging-post-mortem.html). This lets you use the debugger after an exception is raised.

**Quick and dirty way**: This isn't the best way to do it, but a quick way to post-mortem debug is to place the part of the code where you want to check the variables in a try-except block with a breakpoint set in the except block. If you do this with the built-in `breakpoint()` function, you can play with the variables and then continue execution by entering `c` at the debugger prompt.